# Does it matter which line the <br> tag is on?

Tags: html, tags, line-breaks

I have seen two lines written like this:

```
This is the first line.<br>
This is the second line.
```

Or, like this:

```
This is the first line.
<br>This is the second line.
```

Is there any difference between the two, such as for SEO or browser rendering? My guess is they are virtually the same and that the preferred placement is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the first option, It doesn't matter which one you use. The first option suits most workflows better.
It doesn't matter you can use `</br>`, `<br/>` or `<br>`

The placement is a matter of opinion and it don't have anything to do with SEO

Answer (score 0):

i think it's `<br/>`, not `<br>`. And two options are the same

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't matter. Here is a resource on the tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1), line breaks are treated as whitespaces.

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source
>   document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word
>   spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). In particular, user
>   agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing
>   output inter-word space. This can and should be done even in the
>   absence of language information (from the lang attribute, the HTTP
>   "Content-Language" header field (see [RFC2616], section 14.12), user
>   agent settings, etc.).

And

> Line breaks are also white space characters. Note that although
>     and   are defined in [ISO10646] to unambiguously
>   separate lines and paragraphs, respectively, these do not constitute
>   line breaks in HTML, nor does this specification include them in the
>   more general category of white space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the location of the `<br>` tag a matter of preference. It is virtually the same either way. The difference will amount to a space character either before or after the `<br>` tag in the resulting document. I am not aware of any bearing on SEO.

Here is a great reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br